# Interpolate between original and transformed image

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation, homography

In OpenCV I am using feature matching techniques to find matching objects in other images. When I find a matching object I calculate the perspective transformation using the "findHomography" method.
[FindHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography)

This works fine and I can transform images based on this matrix. I have a video which alpha blends between the original and transformed images but now I want to animate the transition between the original and transformed position instead of just alpha blending between the two.

I have the 3x3 Homography matrix which gives me the full transformation but how would I interpolate between no transformation and this? If the 3x3 matrix had single values then I would interpolate between 0 and the Matrix value for however many time steps. However each element of the 3x3 matrix is made up of 3 values, I'm guessing because they are homogenous coordinates.

Could anyone advise the best way to approach this issue.

EDIT

Trying the method suggested by AldurDisciple I am creating the identity matrix with:

```
Mat eye = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_32F);
```

And performing the suggested calculation with:

```
Mat newH = (1-calc) * eye + calc * H;
```

where calc = k/N for the step/total number of steps.

I get an assertion failed error trying to calculate newH with the error being:

```
src1.type() == src2.type() in function scaleAdd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to approach this is to use linear interpolation between the identity matrix (i.e. no transformation) and the homography matrix you estimated with `findHomograhy`.

If `H` is the estimated homography and `N` is the number of time steps you want to use, then the transformation to apply at step k in [0,N] is as follows: H<sub>k</sub> = (1-a<sub>k</sub>) * Id + a<sub>k</sub> * H, with a<sub>k</sub> = k/N.

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion, I received an assertion failed error which I have explained in an edit to my question.

Comment: @Tomsmith It could be that your estimated homography has type `double`, try using `CV_64F` when you create the identity matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works now. I had an issue with integer division as well but now I have a smooth animation.